# android:there are a listview in ScrollView so listview Scrolling not happend.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have this type of layout

```
<LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
    <ImageView/>
    <button>
    <ListView>
</LinearLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```

So in this Case my List view Scrolling not happens and my View Scrolling is perform
i want also perform Listview Scrolling when data is more. and List view is need to put in  Scroll view parent layout so how can solve this problem please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Never put a `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView`. **Never**. You have two options:

1. If you don't necessarily want the `ImageView` and `Button` to scroll away, just remove the `ScrollView`:

   ```
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ...>
       <ImageView .../>
       <Button .../>
       <ListView .../>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. This one is slightly more complicated. Implement a custom list adapter (by extending [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), for example, or one of its subclasses) and, in your `getView` method return the `ImageView` and the `Button` for positions 0 and 1, respectively. This way, your layout will only contain a `ListView`, but its first two items will be the `ImageView` and the `Button`.

P.S.: Never put a `ScrollView` in a `ListView`, either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand for what you try to use ScrollView with ListView too? If your layout is really big than screen, then will be good to use a ScrollView like described here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        android:visibility="visible">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  ..your any xml data
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ListView has internal scroll tool, so you just need to choose a correct way to use it.

Comment: Hardik Gajjar, please don't forget to reply when the problem will solved.

Comment: Dimon I very Thankful for you for Replay me.but My Friend as a Application requirement i need to Put the List view in Scroll View..any way i solve this Problem by Programatically load List view in Layout...thanks again for your Replay