# ScrollView nest ListView,and TextView above ListView, and the textview will be scrolled out of screen

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

the xml file like above.When the ListView is over the screen height, the TextView will be scrolled out of screen...

if set the ListView focusable to false can solve the problem, but i want to know the reason

pls visit the video about my question
Visit https://goo.gl/iEslpl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android:there are a listview in ScrollView so listview Scrolling not happend.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444680/androidthere-are-a-listview-in-scrollview-so-listview-scrolling-not-happend)

Comment: So you want the text to stay fixed on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

refer this library [parallax scrolling](https://github.com/nirhart/parallaxscroll)

more specifically refer *Scroll* *view* *three* *parallaxed* *item*

this is exactly similar to your video demo.

Comment: thx,may be my description is not vey clear. pls visit the video link,[link](https://goo.gl/iEslpl)

Answer (score 0):

problem lies because they all sits in a same linear layout.. that's why it go push out.

try using another linearlayout nesting scrollview, then within it, another linearlayout.

something like.... linear -> scroll -> linear again....

hope this help.

Comment: thx,may be my description is not vey clear. pls visit the video link,[link](https://goo.gl/iEslpl)